# Azure DevOps - How can I make an agent job in a release pipeline continue running even after the release has been canceled?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a release pipeline on Azure Devops. This pipeline create a vm while release and delete the VM after release.
I'm wondering if there are any method to make the pipeline always run a agent job, which is to delete a VM, even when a release has been canceled.
For example, I have 3 jobs in a stage, and I want the 3rd jobs to run even if the release is canceled while job 1 is being processed.

I tried to use: Additional Options - Custom condition using variable expressions, and set it to True according to the document. This worked when job 3 is in progress. However, job 3 didn't run when I canceled a deployment while it was processing job 1.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops

[The Screen shot of the agent job in my release pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96Clw.png)

I tried to set custom condition using variable expression to True in agent job's setting, but the agent job didn't run after I canceled the release.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `always()` condition for that:

```
jobs:
- job: Foo

  steps:
  - script: echo Hello!
    condition: always() # this step will always run, even if the pipeline is canceled

- job: Bar
  dependsOn: Foo
  condition: failed() # this job will only run if Foo fails
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages

EDIT:

for classic - consult the same article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cstages

[image: classic pipeline example]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I have also come across this condition in the documentation, but there doesn't seem to be a way to edit the YAML of the release pipeline. On the other hand, I attempted to use "always()" instead of "True" in the custom condition using variable expression, but the release pipeline reported an error.

Comment: well, there is no issue with editing yaml unless you can show us whats the issue

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding in my description. I'm using the "Classic Release pipeline" but not YAML pipeline. In my organization, we are required to use the Classic Release pipeline. Based on the information I found, classic pipelines do not support the use of YAML files. However, if my information is incorrect, please correct me.

Comment: added an example